# ServiceNow show button if condition is true

Tags: javascript, servicenow, jelly, client-side

I am trying to build a Client Script in ServiceNow - Geneva (function onChange), that does the following:

-> If the user writes something in an empty field a button should appear after change;

This is my code now, it doesn't work -> gives me an X on the form :):

```
function onChange(control, oldValue, newValue, isLoading, isTemplate) {

  //Define the variable and the name of the button


  if (g_form.getValue('work_around') != ''){ 
  var items = $$('BUTTON').each(function(item){  
  if(item.innerHTML.indexOf('Publish Known Error')=== -1){  

      item.show();  
     }
  });

}

}
```

Comment: This code will show all buttons that are not called "Publish Known Error"?  Btw, if you are creating this script on change of the work_around field, there is no need to use "get_value", you could just use "newValue" instead.

Comment: Hi Pete, sorry for the delay of my response. Thank you for the hint with "newValue". The script should only show up the button "Publish Known Error" that has a conditions already (the field needs to have a value). I just want to take out an additional step of save & stay.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a Client Script, I would recommend using an `onChange(<your field>)` UI Policy.  This can be accomplished by setting a Condition of your field not being `NULL` or some other value check.

Your UI Policy can then use the `.append` function to bind your button to an element of your choice.